# How to post string data to API

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I wanted to post a string data to API, I try to send it to server by using the below code. I've check api there by using the postman, it did not pass in the string data into the server. I do not know what is the problem and need help on this.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reqURLStr]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

**//Pass The String to server**
NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"service_type=%@&ParcelSize=%@&ReceiverName=%@&MobileNumber=%@&Email=%@&DropOffHub=%@&PickupHub=%@" ,serviceType,pSize,rName,rMobile,rEmail,dropHubID,pickHubID];

NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:data1];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[data makeRestAPICall:reqURLStr] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);
if(resSrt)
{
    NSLog(@"got response");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"fail to connect");
}
return resSrt;
```

Comment: what error you got from response?

Comment: { status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Sat, 03 Jun 2017 06:37:33 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
}

Comment: I "po respond" and it show me this

Comment: can you please share your request URL ?
so I can look into the metter

Comment: NSString *apiURL = @"http:/api/order/add";
    [self makeRestAPICall: apiURL];

Comment: also need your makeRestAPICall method

Comment: -(NSString*) makeRestAPICall : (NSString*) reqURLStr
{ //the code that I posted first time is in here }

Comment: I will help you brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer

```
-(void)postJsonDataToServer{
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 @"service_type": serviceType,
                                 @"ParcelSize": pSize,
                                 @"ReceiverName": rName,
                                 @"MobileNumber": rMobile,
                                 @"Email" : rEmail,
                                 @"DropOffHub" : dropHubID,
                                 @"PickupHub" : pickHubID
                                 };

    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/api/order/add"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *dataTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest: request
                                                             fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                                 if(data != nil)
                                                                 {
                                                                     NSError *parseError = nil;
                                                                     //If the response is in dictionary format
                                                                     NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

                                                                     //OR
                                                                     //If the response is in array format
                                                                     NSArray *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

                                                                     NSLog(@"The res is - %@",res);

                                                                 }
                                                                 else
                                                                     NSLog(@"Data returned the parameter is nil here");
                                                             }];
    [dataTask resume];


}
```

Comment: Welcome brother